# Rogue email address in Exchange

Tags: exchange-2007

Users can see an old user email contact within the 'To' box in Outlook for a user account that was disabled months ago.

In Exchange there is no mailbox for this user, nor is this email address tied to another mailbox as an additional SMTP.

Any ideas on how to wipe it from this global address list?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but are you sure it's in the global address list and not the local user address list?  We've had that issue before when re-factoring internal groups.

Comment: Not a stupid question. The address is certainly in the global address list, appearing for all active Outlook users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're referring to Outlook autocomplete (and not the actual address list) then each user needs to delete the entry in question from their Outlook autocomplete cache (also called the nickname cache). The following article is for Outlook 2003, but it's relevant for every version of Outlook back to at least Outlook 2000 through Outlook 2010 (as far as I'm aware).

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/about-autocomplete-name-suggesting-HP006376647.aspx

Comment: No it's certainly the Global Address List, as shown in this screenshot - http://tinypic.com/r/j6mo36/5